# ListView и NestedScrollView в Android 4 не работает прокрутка

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinator-layout, swiperefreshlayout

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.0'

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ... >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >

            ...

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeNewsDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Все работает только в Android >= 5, как реализовать прокрутку в 4 и ниже Android?

Comment: пересмотрите разметку. проблемы может создавать вложение ListView в NestedScrollView.

Comment: Смотрите ответ в вопросе-дубликате

Comment: Спасибо всем, перешел на RecyclerView - работает без нареканий